# Определить встряхивание

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Пишу одно приложение. Мне необходимо определять "встряхивание" устройства.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавьте в манифест указание использования датчика - акселерометра

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

2. Создайте класс, реализующий интерфейс `SensorEventListener` в методе `onSensorChanged` обработайте показания сенсора. Например так:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class ShakeDetector implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY = 2.7F;
    private static final int SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS = 500;
    private static final int SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS = 3000;

    private OnShakeListener mListener;
    private long mShakeTimestamp;
    private int mShakeCount;

    public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnShakeListener {
        public void onShake(int count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (mListener != null) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            float gX = x / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gY = y / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gZ = z / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

            float gForce = (float)Math.sqrt(gX * gX + gY * gY + gZ * gZ);

            if (gForce > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY) {
                final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS > now) {
                    return;
                }

                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS < now) {
                    mShakeCount = 0;
                }

                mShakeTimestamp = now;
                mShakeCount++;

                mListener.onShake(mShakeCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Теперь можно воспользоваться этим классом для показа диалога в активити после встряхивания девайса. Для этого создайте объект класса `SensorManager`, из него получите экземпляр класса `Sensor`, который, вместе с нашей реализацией `SensorEventListener` передайте в метод `SensorManager#registerListener()`. Вот код активити:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
    private AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();
        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {

                if (mAlertDialog == null || !mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
                    mDialogBuilder.setMessage("Ух-ты!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    mAlertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();
                    mAlertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```